# NodePort Service not accepting connections : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, kubectl, minikube

I've setup a simple Web API project and made an image. When I run the image directly using docker, I can't access the server using http://localhost:8080, but if I run `docker inspect bridge` I get back :

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "50a9ae0ed8721eaf1e4c5b1dd811d2be55d52e3cd7c012bfeb10d7e163c5d111",
        "Created": "2024-03-12T13:31:17.805598891-06:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "fc3d2b13168f662685e93fdc59c5508a147d6877147b97036d4c47b2f175ed7e": {
                "Name": "dreamy_mclaren",
                "EndpointID": "5173755a7c8158a30b195ec4d752f029eac0d84785ce20d2968ee18544374775",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

So then I try a GET request to http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/platforms and get back the expected response. I'm not sure where this subnet/gateway is coming from. By default I would expect to be able to use `localhost`. I went ahead and pushed the image to Dockerhub regardless. This issue is compounded when I try to setup a Deployment for this image, and a NodePort service:

platforms-depl.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: itunbridge/platformservice:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

platforms-np-srv.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Then I run:
`kubectl apply -f platforms-depl.yaml`
and
`kubectl apply -f platforms-np-srv.yaml`

I can see which port was assigned with `kubectl get services`:

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        46m
platformservice-srv   NodePort    10.104.221.184   <none>        80:30201/TCP   44m
```

I then try: `minikube service platformservice-srv --url` which gives me a response of
http://192.168.59.100:30201

But none of these addresses give a response:

- http://192.168.59.100:30201/api/platforms
- http://10.104.221.184:30201/api/platforms
- http://localhost:30201/api/platforms
- http://172.17.0.2:30201/api/platforms
- http://10.104.221.184:30201/api/platforms
- http://10.244.0.5:30201/api/platforms

[image: From the Kubernetes Extension for VS Code]

Comment: In your local URL, you're accessing port 8080.  Does this need to be the `targetPort:` of the Service (and the `containerPort:` in the Deployment, though that's not used in this setup)?

Comment: I just used 8080:80 in my port mapping to run the image in a Docker container locally. But no - the application is listening on default port 80

Comment: If you're directly accessing the container IP (and you're on a native-Linux system where this is possible) then it's bypassing `ports:`.  If you started the container with a `-p 8080:80` option and `localhost:8080` is giving a "connection refused" or similar error, that could be the same cause, where the container process is using port 8080.

Comment: @DavidMaze I see what you're saying now. I've changed the platforms-np-srv.yaml:
```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30201
```
re-apply, then run `kubectl port-forward platforms-depl-5c4d9f944c-j8qqx 8080:8080` and now I can access: http://localhost:8080/api/platforms

I'm confused as to why I can't access http://localhost:30201/api/platforms directly

Comment: `kubectl port-forward` directly connects to a Pod via the Kubernetes API, it doesn't use a Service at all.

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, the default `ASPNETCORE_URLS` Environment variable was set to `http://+:8080` (as opposed to `http://+80`). After I updated my docker file:

```
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "PlatformService.dll" ]
```

I pushed the new image to Docker Hub, then set the new image in my deployment:
`kubectl set image deployment/platforms-depl platformservice=itunbridge/platformservice` and `kubectl rollout status deployment/platforms-depl` then the NodePort configuration I had originally:

(platforms-np-srv.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30201
```

This works with value `targetPort: 80` and I could access the endpoint by finding the IP assigned to `minikube ip` (http://192.168.59.100:30201/api/platforms)

A big thank you to @DavidMaze for pointing this out and getting me to realize my Web API app was listening on port 8080.